# ¿Cómo puedo crear el constructor solicitado?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio de programación orientada a objetos, más especificamente en Java. Quisiera consultar si alguien me puede echar una mano. Dice así:

> Cree una clase con dos variables tipo int y dos métodos, el primer método debe tener dos parámetros que le permitan recibir como argumentos los valores digitados desde teclado pero en el método main, el método solo debe mostrar el mensaje con los valores que hayan recibido los parámetros. El segundo método, mostrará la suma de esos valores. Crear un constructor personalizado que acepte los parámetros correspondientes a la variable de la clase. Implemente la clase e invoque los métodos.

El problema es, dónde se crea el objeto, el constructor lleva unos parámetros, estos parámetros son los mismos para todos los métodos pero no sé cómo darle valores a los parámetros ya que si lo hago de la forma:

```
a=s.nextInt();
```

No me lo permite porque necesito el objeto para acceder a las variables de la clase.

Anexo mi código:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ejercicio2
{
  public int a , b ;

  public void param(int a, int b )
  {
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b; 
    System.out.println(a + b ) ; 
  }

  public void muestra() 
  {
    System.out.println("suma" + (a+b) ) ;
  }

  public Ejercicio2(int c , int d )
  {

  }

}

class DemoEjercicio2
{
  public static void main ( String args[] )

  {
    Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in) ;

    a=s.nextInt();
    b=s.nextInt();

    Ejercicio2 e=new Ejercicio2(a , b);
    e.param(a,b);
    e.muestra(); 

  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, eso explica tu duda. En el futuro, nunca te olvides de hacer una pregunta específica. Y si se trata de un error, incluye los detalles del error en tu pregunta. Si no haces eso, dará la impresión que quieres que alguien haga el trabajo entero por ti, y aunque siempre habrá personas que estarán dispuestos a regalarte código, esto no te ayudará a aprender.

Comment: muchas gracias , es mi primer post , no estoy muy acostumbrado a hacer este tipo de cosas

y lo se , lo pregunte , porque ya habia pasado bastante tiempo tratando de hacerlo y no me compilaba 

tomare en cuenta tus consejos

Answer (score 3):

Tu código quedaría así:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ejercicio2 {
    public int a, b;

    public Ejercicio2(int a, int b) { // un constructor con dos parametros
        param(a, b);
    }

    public void param(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void muestra() {
        System.out.println("Número A: " + a + " - Numero B: " + b);
    }
}

class DemoEjercicio2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca dos número:");
        int numA = s.nextInt();
        int numB = s.nextInt();

        Ejercicio2 e = new Ejercicio2(numA, numB);
        e.muestra();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> el problema es, donde se crea el objeto , el constructor lleva unos parametros , estos parametros son los mismos para todos los metodos pero , no se como darle valores a los parametros ya que si lo hago de la forma `a=s.nextInt();` no me lo permite porque necesito el objeto para acceder a las variables de la clase

Parece que hay un pequeña confusión con la porción siguiente:

```
a=s.nextInt();
b=s.nextInt();

Ejercicio2 e=new Ejercicio2(a , b);
```

Parece que estás bajo la impresión que las variables `a` y `b` son las mismas que están definidas en la clase `Ejercicio2`. Pero esto no es el caso. Estas son variables completamente distintas, y es al pasarselas al constructor de `Ejercicio2` que los valores son asignados al `a` y `b` dentro de la clase `Ejercicio2`.

De hecho, no hay ni siquiera necesidad de que estas variables se llamen `a` y `b`. Puedes hacerlo, pero no es necesario.

Una vez que entiendes que estas variables son distintas, seguramente puedes comprender que el problemaes que estás usando variables sin declararlas.

Por eso, una forma de corregir este problema en particular es así:

```
int a=s.nextInt(); // nota el "int" en frente
int b=s.nextInt(); // nota el "int" en frente

Ejercicio2 e=new Ejercicio2(a , b);
```

Y para demostrar que esas variables no tienen nada que ver con las que están la clase `Ejercicio2`, puedes cambiarles el nombre y probar que eso funciona también:

```
int x=s.nextInt(); // nota el "x"
int y=s.nextInt(); // nota el "y"

Ejercicio2 e=new Ejercicio2(x , y); // nota el "x" y "y"
```

Ahora bien, el problema siguiente es que tu constructor está vacío:

```
public Ejercicio2(int c , int d )
{

}
```

Aquí si tienes que aceptar los parámetros `c` y `d` y asignarlos a las variables `a` y `b` dentro de tu clase `Ejercicio2`. Estoy seguro que con esfuerzo lograrás hacer los cambios necesarios para que te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

el constructor sirve para crear un objeto nuevo pero con atributos ya establecidos, te crea en un estado de inicio, a partir de tus funciones podrás varias el estado de inicio, haciendo modificaciones en tus variables(atributos) propios de tu objeto.

digo esto de arriba por que puedes crear varios constructores, para que tu objeto pueda iniciarse en varios estados de inicio.

modificando tu codigo, adicionando un contructor pruebalo.

```
import java.util.*;
class Ejercicio2 {
    public int a, b;

    public Ejercicio2(int a, int b) { 
        param(a, b);
    }
    public Ejercicio2() { 
        param(5, 6);
    }


    public void param(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void muestra() {
        System.out.println("Número A: " + a + " - Numero B: " + b);
    }
}

class DemoEjercicio2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca dos número:");
        int numA = s.nextInt();
        int numB = s.nextInt();
        Ejercicio2 e = new Ejercicio2(numA, numB);
        e.muestra();
    }
}
```